# Thyristor latching problem

Tags: 555, thyristor

I am attempting to make a circuit which triggers a 555 astable. The input is one of those IR beam break sensors with the output of the phototransistor going to a NOT gate and the output of that is connected to the gate of the thyristor through a 1k resistor. That thyristor is then powering the 555. The idea is that, when the beam is broken, the 555 will be triggered.

The only way that I can get it to work is by adding an LED in parallel with the 555, but it is quite unreliable. I think the problem is that the drain-source current is less than the holding and latching current, which are specified as 5 mA and 6 mA respectively. When I measured it, the current drawn by the 555 dropped as low as 3 mA, so this seems plausible.

Does anyone know of a "low current thyristor" or something else that would get this working reliably?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some diagram of what you are doing would be useful, and a reason why you use the thyristor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean an SCR you can use a parametric search at a distributor to find parts with low holding current.. eg. TS110-7 2mA maximum. You can minimize it by keeping the gate-cathode resistance relatively large.

There are thyristors with much lower holding current (eg. 2N6028) but they are not going to work without a lot of modifications to your circuit.

Or just connect two transistors as a thyristor. The value of the emitter-base resistor(s) will determine the holding current and you can make those resistors very high value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWuSee.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here you can see that it typically holds at < 100uA. 
[image]